# File upload from NodeJS to Java Spring framework

Tags: java, node.js, spring

I need a simple **File Upload** (`JavaScript` code example) from `NodeJS` to Java Spring framework method as followed.

Any help (approach) would be very much appreciated !

**Java Code in Spring framework:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<FileJobResultBase> upload(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest
) throws IOException {
    try {
        String storageName = httpServletRequest.getHeader("storageName");
        String path = httpServletRequest.getHeader("path");
        String fileName = httpServletRequest.getHeader("fileName");
        String fileType = httpServletRequest.getHeader("fileType");
        String context = httpServletRequest.getHeader("context");
        String organization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("organization");
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(httpServletRequest.getInputStream());
        FileJobResultBase fileJobResultBase = fileManagerService.upload(bytes, storageName, path, fileName, fileType == null ? "unknown" : fileType,authorization,organization, context);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(fileJobResultBase, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return  exceptionHandling( e);

    }


}
```

**Currently my `NodeJS` code (but it's no good)**

```
module.exports = {

  create : function(req, res) {
    var file = Object.keys(req.body.file).map(function(value, index) {     return [value]; });
    var headerSignature = APISigningService.getHeaderSignature();

}
```

Comment: please share your javascript and error you get while you execute this.